# How to upload large video to server (php) using AFNetworking 3.0 (Obj-C)

Tags: php, ios, xcode, upload, afnetworking

I am trying to create a simple video upload task using **AFNetworking 3.0**. I know how to upload smaller videos the I need to be able to upload (stream) large files (longer videos). Below is the code I use to upload currently. Also, I use PHP on the server side, is there any special change is needed?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://v.afrazsiddiqui.com/?cmd=post&id=%@",[UDM returnValueforkey:@"userid"]] parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:self.videoURL name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime" error:nil];
} error:nil];


AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat done = self.view.frame.size.width*uploadProgress.fractionCompleted;
        [self updateProgressWithPercentage:done];
    });
}
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        errorUploading=YES;
    }
    else {
        JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
        if ([[JSON valueForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
            [self reloadProfile];
        }
        else if ([[JSON valueForKey:@"Error"] isEqualToString:@"Upload"]) {
            if (!errorUploading) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vlog Error" message:@"An error occurred when trying to post your vlog." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No, Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```